# How to change the default first week day number to 0 in Calendar module Python

Tags: python, django, date, calendar

I have implemented a logic in my code where I need to calculate the date/day considering Sunday as the starting day of week.
 When I am using this code

```
import calendar
day_number = calendar.weekday(2014, 01, 19)
```

Its returning day_number as 6, but I need it should return as 0, since 19 Jan 2014 is a sunday.

I have also tried to use this:

```
calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.SUNDAY)
```

But still the sunday number remains as 6. Is there any setting using which we can set the sunday number as 0, and the week numbers should appear as below

```
'sun': 0, 
'mon': 1,
'tue': 2,
'wed': 3,
'thu': 4,
'fri': 5,
'sat': 6,
```

Answer (score 5):

`setfirstweekday` affects only display functions like `prmonth`:

```
>>> calendar.prmonth(2014, 1)
    January 2014
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30 31
>>> calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.SUNDAY)
>>> calendar.prmonth(2014, 1)
    January 2014
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31
```

How about using modulo?

```
>>> (calendar.weekday(2014, 1, 19) + 1) % 7
0
```

Comment: Yeah, modulo should work.But again if i use this calendar.day_name[0] its returning 'Monday' instead of 'Sunday'

Comment: @sandeep, Why not define your own `day_name`? `day_name = calendar.day_name[6:] + calendar.day_name[:6]`

Comment: Yeah, ok. I can define a dictionary containing day names as per my wish and then refer that in the code.

Comment: I also think the calendar should react this way, if we' re going to define our own logic, why use a library at all, right?